# i Cant make this method works on Apps script classroom API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

```js
var ClassroomID=305126825015
var TeacherslistID=[mike@gtrainerdemo.com, lola@gtrainerdemo.com, jeronimo@gtrainerdemo.com, antonio@gtrainerdemo.dimensiongrafica.com, andrew@gtrainerdemo.com];

for (K = 0; K < TeacherslistID.length; K++)
{
Classroom.Courses.Teachers.remove({"userId":TeacherslistID[K]},ClassroomID);
}
```

ERROR: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.teachers.delete failed with error: Requested entity was not found.

I confirmed the ID form the teacher i used to create te course works well on other methods as classroom.courses.teachers.create, so don't know were i make the mistake here. may i miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a teacher using Classroom API in Apps Script, you need to use `Classroom.Courses.Teachers.remove(courseId: string, userId: string)`

> You can check the arguments when you type `Classroom.Courses.Teachers.remove(` and wait for the support tab to be displayed.

[image]

### Your code should be like this:

```
var TeacherslistID=['mike@gtrainerdemo.com', 'lola@gtrainerdemo.com', 'jeronimo@gtrainerdemo.com', 'antonio@gtrainerdemo.dimensiongrafica.com', 'andrew@gtrainerdemo.com'];

for (K = 0; K < TeacherslistID.length; K++)
{
  Classroom.Courses.Teachers.remove(ClassroomID, TeacherslistID[K]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize that the order in that instruction was different.
Sometimes when you have been with something for many hours, the solution is simpler than it seems.

Thank you so much.